# octomap_ros on ros 2 humble

Tags: slam, navigation, ros2, octomap, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Both octomap and octomap_ros are available on ros 2 humble, as debian packages. But the documentation linked is for ros noetic. Making some google searches on the subject I understood that there are no step-by-step tutorials on octomap ros 1 nor ros 2 - so I tried experimenting, and got some success but I have some questions.

1. Can octomap_server take pointcloud2 data directly from sensor, such as zed2i's zed2i/zed_node/depth/depth_registered topic,
   or does it have to rely on another mapper such as rtabmap? Can octomap work standalone, as a replacement to rtabmap, or it needs rtabmap or some other node to run and process the point cloud. zed2i's output is sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2 and this is what octomap expects but, for some reason it will not publish /octomap_binary nor /octomap_full
2. instead of zed2i's point cloud data, I have feeded in /voxel_cloud from rtabmap, and octomap then somewhat works. there is nothing about this in the documentation
3. at the beginning octomap prints a warning about not being able to opening a path. in the source code:

const auto filename = declare_parameter("octomap_path", "");
if (!openFile(filename)) {
RCLCPP_WARN(get_logger(), "Could not open file %s", filename.c_str());
}

Does octomap expect a .bt file always, or can it operate without a bt file

Best regards,
Can Altineller

[edit]

on further inspection, i found out that rtabmap also publishes octomap topics under /rtabmap/octomap ...
is this embedded to rtabmap now, and we use octomap to just save produced map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413030/octomap_ros-on-ros-2-humble/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2023-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With octomap_server, you can feed it a point cloud from the sensor and its pose through TF, it should generate the octomap on its own. There is a minimal example here:

- ros1: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/kinetic-devel/octomap_server/launch/octomap_mapping.launch
- ros2: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/ros2/octomap_server/launch/octomap_mapping.launch.xml

rtabmap integrated octomap library to generate octomap topics in same format than octomap_server (they can be visualized in RVIZ with octomap rviz plugins). When using rtabmap for octomap, you don't need octomap_server. The advantage of the integration in rtabmap is that on loop closure detection, the octomap will be updated accordingly. With octomap_server, it assumes non-drifting pose or if there is a correction of the pose, it won't re-update the previous cells seen so far.

cheers,
Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2023-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1